# Why use "a" instead of "an" in this context?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, so

[Source](https://sherlock-holm.es/stories/pdf/a4/1-sided/houn.pdf)

> We know now why Stapleton looked with disfavour upon his sister’s suitor—even when that suitor was so eligible **a** one as Sir Henry.

Is the reason for using **a** instead of **an** is idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the rule is "use an before a vowel **sound**". Many people forget that fact. It's not about whether the word starts with a vowel or a consonant, it's whether it starts with a vowel sound or a consonant sound.

In "one" we pronounce it wʌn... the w sound is the leading sound, which is a consonant. We say "a walrus" and "a wish", so we also say "a one".